# Coded UIStepper not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.1, uistepper

After not finding an answer I have to again ask you all for help. I am creating a `UIStepper` programatically but it will not display. Labels, buttons, and switches are all displaying properly so I must be missing something related to the stepper.

Elsewhere in my code I declare and initialize `UIView *v` and `NSMutableArray *steppers`, and declare `UIStepper *st`. The code to create the stepper is:

```
st = [[UIStepper alloc] init];
st.frame = CGRectMake(xnear, ypos, 0, 0);
[st addTarget:self action:@selector(stepper1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[st setMinimumValue:0];
[st setMaximumValue:99];
[st setWraps:NO];
[st setContinuous:NO];
[v addSubview:st];
[steppers addObject:st];
```

At runtime `xnear = 100` and `ypos = 250`, so the stepper is within the display. A label immediately above, and a text field immediately below, are displaying. Other questions regarding the `UIStepper` state the width and height are ignored, so I used 0 for both. Is there anything obviously wrong with this code?

Comment: screenshot please...

Comment: Few things need to be checked here. First, are you sure that the `xnear` and `ypos` return the correct value? (Probably, NSLogging them might show you the value). Second, has the `v` (view) been added to the self.view in first place? Because, I ran your code with some value instead of `xnear` and `ypos`. It works for me.

Comment: I have not been NSLogging the values, but have checked them stepping through the debugger. `xnear` and `ypos` are exactly where they need to be. And `v` has been properly instantiated.

With a little more work this morning I am having no problems with text fields, buttons, labels, sliders, or switches. But when I try adding a `UIStepper` or `UISegmentedControl` the object is not showing up in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting height and width of UIStepper as 0

```
st.frame = CGRectMake(xnear, ypos, 0, 0);
```

give some height and width

```
st.frame = CGRectMake(xnear, ypos,200, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, quite frankly, embarrassing. A custom background color was set for the `UIView` and no color was set for the control. I was able to get the stepper to show up with the following line of code:

```
st.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Similarly, the `UISegmentedControl *sc` showed up when I added:

```
sc.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Thanks for the help and sorry to waste your time!